# Difference between skimage Sobel filter and OpenCV Sobel filter

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.sobel

https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gacea54f142e81b6758cb6f375ce782c8d

I have been reading the source code for both of these operators, and even tried and use the kernel taken from `scikit image's` Sobel operator, yet the results from these two are vastly different (with the value of `scikit sobel` being around the range of `10^-6` but the cv2 in the hundreds), and I don't think I know image processing well enough to figure out why anyone knows their difference?

```
gX = cv2.Sobel(grayscaled_img, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=3)
gY = cv2.Sobel(grayscaled_img, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=3)
gX = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gX)
gY = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gY)
combined = cv2.addWeighted(gX, 0.5, gY, 0.5, 0)
sob = combined.var()
sob2 = skimage.filters.sobel(grayscaled_img)
```

For Sobel in cv2?

Comment: The difference is likely the normalization. Once normalized by dividing by the sum of absolute values and the other does no normalization. This has been asked before. Search the forum or Google

Comment: In your OpenCV are you using both dx and dy or only one or the other?  Skimage does only one or the other, not both at the same time.

Comment: Please show your code for both tools.

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you I'll try and search for it

Comment: Print the filters and show us what you get.

Comment: I've added the code as well now

Comment: Sobel in Skimage is using the magnitude of the two components. That is the sqrt of the sum of squares. You are just taking the average of the two absolute values in your OpenCV code.

Comment: Using cv2.addWeighted is just a very coarse approximation of the magnitude. Use cv2.cartToPolar https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gac5f92f48ec32cacf5275969c33ee837d to get magnitude and angle information from gX and gY or cv2.magnitude if you only need the magnitide.

Comment: AFAIK, many OpenCV operations handle grayscale with range [0,255]. Not all operations convert to it though. And Skimage handles grayscale with range [0,1].